# incorrect result when comparing records from different databases

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I have the following data [image]

I would like to compare these data. So, I use this code:

```
drop view sms4_table;
create view sms4_table as
select snumber,cast(to_char(cdrdate,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')as varchar2(14))as cdrdate
      from database1@db
      where snumber='123456789101098'
and (cdrdate between to_date ('05/07/2014 00:00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
and to_date ('05/07/2014 23:59:59','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));

drop view sms3_table;
create view sms3_table as
select cast (substr(snumber,1,15) as varchar2(15)) as snumber,timestamp as answertime
     FROM database2 
          where snumber='123456789101098A';
                and timestamp like '20140705%'

select sms4_table.snumber, sms4_table.cdrdate, sms3_table.snumber, sms3_table.answertime
       from sms4_table
       left join sms3_table
on  sms4_table.cdrdate=sms3_table.answertime
and sms4_table.snumber=sms3_table.snumber
where sms3_table.snumber is null;
```

I have **20** records in database1 and **19** records in database2. The only difference between the databases is that two of the records are duplicated (this with snumber 123456789101098 and cdrdate 20140705033021) in database1. However, when I run the script above I didn't receive the difference. I only receive -

> 0 rows selected

Could you please back me up. How to correct the script to show this difference - snumber 123456789101098 and cdrdate 20140705033021?

Thanks for helping me in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a row number pseudo-column to both views so that duplicate values can be distinguished:

```
create view sms4_table as
select snumber,
  to_char(cdrdate,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') as cdrdate,
  row_number() over (partition by snumber,
    to_char(cdrdate,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')) as rn
from database1@db
where snumber='123456789101098'
and cdrdate between to_date ('05/07/2014 00:00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
and to_date ('05/07/2014 23:59:59','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');

create view sms3_table as
select substr(snumber,1,15) as snumber,
  timestamp as answertime,
  row_number() over (partition by substr(snumber,1,15), timestamp) as rn
from database2 
where snumber='123456789101098A'
and timestamp like '20140705%';
```

Then include the `rn` pseudo-column in the join; I've changed it to a full outer join so you can spot problems either way.

```
select sms4_table.snumber, sms4_table.cdrdate,
  sms3_table.snumber, sms3_table.answertime
from sms4_table
full outer join sms3_table
on sms4_table.cdrdate = sms3_table.answertime
and sms4_table.snumber = sms3_table.snumber
and sms4_table.rn = sms3_table.rn
where sms3_table.snumber is null
or sms4_table.snumber is null;
```

For your duplicated values `sms4_table` will now have:

```
snumber         cdrdate         rn
--------------- -------------- ---
123456789101098 20140705033021   1
123456789101098 20140705033021   2
```

while `sms3_table` will only have:

```
snumber         answertime      rn
--------------- -------------- ---
123456789101098 20140705033021   1
```

If you only join on the first two columns then both records in view 4 will match the record in view 3 - as your original query was doing. But if you include `rn` in the join condition then only the first row matches, and second row with `rn = 2` does not.

You don't really need to create views if this is a one-off task, you could just use in-line views (subqueries).

Comment: I run the script with this rn pseudo-column and I receive 39 records (20 from the one side and 19 on the other side). However, I would like to receive only one record, which contains duplicated value. Do you know how I could do this?

Comment: Based on this, and the fact that you got 0 rows before, none of the rows match. Inspect the data in the output carefully and work out why they aren't matching exactly.

Comment: @Kristiana - sorry, bad copy-and-paste; right side of the new condition changed to `rn`.

Comment: Thank you very much Alex. Now the scrip is working :)

Comment: Could you please explain me a little more about this pseudo-column. I can't understand why with the pseudo-column the script is working and without it the script is not working.